# Split Javascript values in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, cordova

I need to split an array into an JSON array which should be following pattern.

```
{{"url":url, "north":True "side":True}, {"url":url, "north":False, "side":True}}
```

I get the url parameter with this code. As you can see [here](http://imgur.com/yDN8d2g), this code displays 3 checkboxes where you can select if the picture is north, on the side or if you want to select it.

```
if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete") {
    xmlDoc = xmlHttp.responseXML;
    pictureTemp = [document.getElementById("imgfilename")];

    $('.login-form').append('<button onclick="sendAuswahl()">Send</button><br>');
    for (var i = 0; i < xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("imgfilename").length; i++) {
      pictureTemp[i] = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("imgfilename")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
      $('.login-form').append('<input type="checkbox" name="north" value="North"><input type="checkbox" name="orientation" value="Side"><input type="checkbox" name="url" value='+ pictureTemp[i]+'><img src='+ pictureTemp[i]+' width="50%"></br>');
    };
}
```

To get all ticked checkboxes, I use this code:

```
var arrayUrl = $("input[name='url']:checked").map(function(){
      return this.value;
}).get()

var arrayNorth = $("input[name='north']:checked").map(function(){
      return "True";
}).get()

var arrayOrientation = $("input[name='orientation']:checked").map(function(){
      return "True";
}).get()
```

To convert the selection to a JavaScript object and to get the pattern which I described above, I use this:

```
var picture = {
      "url" : arrayUrl,
      "North" : arrayNorth,
      "Side" : arrayOrientation
};
```

But when I alert the value of a selected image I get this:

```
{"url":http://www.example.com, "north":True "side":True}
```

And when I select 2 images I get this:

```
{"url":http://www.example.com, http://www.example2.com, "north":True "side":False}
```

Instead of this:

```
{{"url":http://www.example.com, "north":True "side":False}, {"url":http://www.example2.com, "north":False, "side":True}}
```

So my question is now: How can I adept the values in the pattern which I've described above?

Answer (score 0):

```
var picture = [];
$.each(arrayUrl, function(index,val) {
    val = {
        "url" : val,
        "North" : arrayNorth[index],
        "Side" : arrayOrientation[index]
    };
    picture.push(val);
});
```

Comment: I get a SyntaxError: Unexpected EOF on `val = '{`

Comment: try it now using json

Comment: Ok, but when I take 2 pictures I get this:
`[{"url":http://www.example.com, "north":True "side":False}, {"url":http://www.example2.com, "side":False}]
`
The second picture has no north key value pair

Comment: And when the first picture has not checked the side checkbox but the second picture has, I get this:
`[{"url":http://www.example.com, "north":False "side":True}, {"url":http://www.example2.com, "north":False}]`

Answer (score 0):

```
var picture = [];
$(arrayUrl).each(function(index) {
    picture.push({
        "url": arrayUrl[index],
        "North": arrayNorth[index],
        "Side": arrayOrientation[index]
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! It nearly works, but when the first picture has not checked the side checkbox but the second picture has, I get this:
`[{"url":http://www.example.com, "north":False "side":True}, {"url":http://www.example2.com, "north":False}]`

Comment: For that you need to make changes in the arrayUrl, arrayNorth and arrayOrientation JSON array. You have to make changes in arrayNorth and arrayOrientation as it contains all selected and unselected value in sequence.

Comment: So I need to get all status if they are checked or not from arrayNorth and arrayOrientation and not only the checked ones?

Comment: Yes for maintaining the sequence of values in array

Comment: Hmm I tried it, but I always get the wrong sequence.